# ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '511d50c0' at 'null' in 'null'

Tags: apache-storm

I am new to Storm. I installed zookeeper, storm , java im my local machine. Zookeeper is working fine. When I tried to run nimbus using the command storm nimbus, I am getting the following error.

ERROR StatusLogger Unable to access file:///log4j2/cluster.xml
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '511d50c0' at 'null' in 'null'

I checked the storm.yaml file and its all perfect. Can somebody help me out in solving this.

Answer (score 2):

What is your storm version?

In newer versions,The problem is caused by the old configuration of config file: storm/conf/storm.yaml. In version 1.1 of storm, instead of nimbus.host, use nimbus.seeds.

Comment: I had to change the configuration file for storm. I used nimbus.seeds only. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Change the java config parameter as

" -Dlog4j2.configurationFile "
This will work fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

the log4j.configuration expects the file to be in the classpath, while log4j.configurationFile expects it as a file path.

change properties file or configuration file location pattern: from : -Dlog4j.configuration=file To: -Dlog4j.configurationFile